# Why Bootstrap's class navbar-fixed-top z-index=1030?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web

In my coding, I see the class **navbar-fixed-top** in Bootstrap v3.3.7.
Why the z-index = 1030?

[image]

Comment: what is question and what do you want? why do you not need z-index =1030? please check anout z-index you will get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of using z-index is for move the content in z-axis. Since you are using the **navbar-fixed-top** class, the header will always stick to the top of the page. But scrolling the page down will hide the header. In order to scroll the page content below header, z-index is used.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is a framework with MANY components that **need to work together**:

- the modal should be over a component like a navbar, with the modal overlay in-between obviously
- a tooltip should also display above any navbar, etc

These values are defined in **[`less/variables.less`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/less/variables.less#L265-L278)**.

```
//-- Z-index master list
//
// Warning: Avoid customizing these values. They're used for a bird's eye view
// of components dependent on the z-axis and are designed to all work together.
//
// Note: These variables are not generated into the Customizer.

@zindex-navbar:            1000;
@zindex-dropdown:          1000;
@zindex-popover:           1060;
@zindex-tooltip:           1070;
@zindex-navbar-fixed:      1030;
@zindex-modal-background:  1040;
@zindex-modal:             1050;
```

Current v4 has them defined (in now default v4-beta branch on GitHub) in `scss/_variables.scss`

Trying to define them with *magic values* is a recipe for disaster, even in projects 10x smaller than a framework like BS: 2 months later a wild page appears with a case never seen before like a tooltip displaying above a submenu, etc. Having a convention applied by every person modifying the CSS is a must have (that includes "you lone developer" and "you lone developer in 2 months" ^^)

General note about Bootstrap: a LOT of things can be modified with this file alone, if you've the skills to recompile CSS with that Gulp workflow.